# ¿Cómo cuento ocurrencias con Grep?

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos, grep

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio concreto, a priori bastante sencillo, pero me tiene un tanto bloqueado.

> Encontrar cuantas veces aparece la palabra "network" en la salida "lshw"

Bien, lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

```sh
lshw -class network | grep "network" | wc -l
```

El problema aparece cuando me piden que solo puedo hacerlo con un *pipe* y 2 comandos, grosso modo, en el caso mencionado, si uso `grep` no puedo usar `wc` y viceversa.

Y claro, todos mis razonamientos acabo en el mismo sitio, *3 pipes* y 2 comandos.

¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: `grep` tiene un `-c` para que te muestre la cuenta de ocurrencias.

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de usar `-c`:

```
grep -c "concepto a buscar"
```

De `man grep`:

> **-c, --count**
> Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.